# Where-Object, Select-Object and ForEach-object - Differences and Usage

Tags: powershell

`Where-Object`, `Select-Object` and `ForEach-Object`

I am a PowerShell beginner. I don't understand too much. Can someone give examples to illustrate the differences and usage scenarios between them?

Comment: `help Where-Object` ; `help Select-Object` ; `help ForEach-Object`

Comment: Specific usage scenarios?

Comment: You need to read the help. It will give you examples if you specify the `-full` parameter. For example: `help ForEach-Object -full` will show you all the parameters, parameter sets, and examples. Be sure to run `Update-Help` to make sure your help files are up to date. You can always run `help ForEach-Object -online` to be taken to the online page which may be more up to date.

Comment: This is a good question. The fact that is it's very basic doesn't make it unsuitable for SO in any way. It's a good opportunity to have this clarified as a comparison, which you won't find in `help`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two things in there: filtering and iterating through a collection.

1. **Filtering**:
   principle: Always use filtering left as much as possible. These two commands do the same thing, but the second one won't transmit a huge chunk of data through the pipe (or network):

```
Get-Process | where-Object {$_.Name -like 'chrome'} | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\processes.csv'
Get-Process -Name chrome | Export-Csv c:\temp\processes.csv
```

This is great when working with huge lists of computers or big files.

Many commandlets have their own filtering capabilities. Run get `Get-Help get-process -full` to see what they offer before piping.

2. **iterating through collections**:

Here you have 3 possibilities:

- **batch cmdlets** is commandlet built in capability of passing a collection to another commandlet:

```
Get-Service -name BITS,Spooler,W32Time | Set-Service -startuptype Automatic
```

- **WMI methods** - WMI uses it's own way of doing the first one (different syntax)

```
gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "description like '%intel%'" | EnableDHCP()
```

- **enumerating objects** - iterating through the list:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "name = 'BITS'" | ForEach-Object -process { $_.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"P@ssw0rd") }
```

**Credits**:
I found explanations that cleared the mess in my head around all these things in a book called : **Learn Powershell in a month of lunches** (chapters 9 and 13 in this case)

Comment: You have two "|" in the first code example.

Answer (score 9):

If you are at all familiar with either LINQ or SQL then it should be much easier to understand because it uses the same concepts for the same words with a slight tweak.

#### `Where-Object`

is used for filtering out objects from the pipeline and is similar to how SQL filters rows. Here, objects are compared against a condition, or optionally a `ScriptBlock`, to determine whether it should be passed on to the next cmdlet in the pipeline. To demonstrate:

```
# Approved Verbs
Get-Verb | Measure-Object # count of 98
Get-Verb | Where-Object Verb -Like G* | Measure-Object # 3

# Integers 1 to 100
1..100 | Measure-Object # count of 100
1..100 | Where-Object {$_ -LT 50} | Measure-Object # count of 49
```

This syntax is usually the most readable when **not** using a `ScriptBlock`, but is necessary if you want to refer to the object itself (not a property) or for more complicated boolean results. Note: many resources will recommend (as @[Iftimie Tudor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7103406/iftimie-tudor) mentions) trying to filter sooner (more left) in the pipeline for performance benefits.

#### `Select-Object`

is used for filtering properties of an object and is similar to how SQL filters columns. Importantly, it transforms the pipeline object into a new `PSCustomObject` that only has the requested properties with the object's values copied. To demonstrate:

```
Get-Process
Get-Process | Select-Object Name,CPU
```

Note, though, that this is only the standard usage. Explore its parameter sets using `Get-Help Select-Object` where it has similar row-like filtering capabilities like only getting the first n objects from the pipeline (aka, `Get-Process | Select-Object -First 3`) that continue onto the next cmdlet.

#### `ForEach-Object`

is like your `foreach` loops in other languages, with its own *important* flavour. In fact, PowerShell also has a `foreach` loop of its own! These may be easily confused but are operationally quite different. The main visual difference is that the `foreach` loop **cannot** be used in a pipeline, but `ForEach-Object` can. The latter, `ForEach-Object`, is a cmdlet (`foreach` is not) and can be used for transforming the current pipeline or for running a segment of code against the pipeline. It is really the most flexible cmdlet there is.

The best way to think about it is that it is the body of a loop, where the current element, `$_`, is coming from the pipeline and any output is passed onto the next cmdlet. To demonstrate:

```
# Transform
Get-Verb | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Verb) comes from the group $($_.Group)"}
# Retrieve Property
Get-Verb | ForEach-Object Verb
# Call Method
Get-Verb | ForEach-Object GetType
# Run Code
1..100 | ForEach-Object {
    $increment = $_ + 1
    $multiplied = $increment * 3
    Write-Output $multiplied
}
```