# For each loop in powershell to run parallely on different servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to perform disk cleanup on 500 VDIs using below script and create a proper report with VDI status and disk space detail using below script .But I want to run the cleanup parallely on all VDIs not one after other as done in for each loop ..Hence I have tried foreach -parallel but its not working .Please suggest how can I modify this script to perform cleanup parallely on all VDI

```
$InputFile="H:\Ignio\Lastlogon\vdi list 3.csv"
$AllVDI = Get-Content $InputFile
$collection = @()
$file = "C:\report.csv"
$Starters = (Get-Date)

ForEach-Object -parallel ($VDI in $AllVDI){

 if((Test-Connection -ComputerName $VDI -count 1 -ErrorAction 0)) {
     $Isonline = "Online"
 if((Test-WSMan -ComputerName $VDI -ErrorAction 0)){
     $Remoting = "Enabled"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VDI -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {

                             Stop-Service -Name wuauserv -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Ignore -WarningAction Ignore
                             Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Temp\*" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
                             Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\download\*" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
                                   Start-Service -Name wuauserv -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Ignore    }
    $Space = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VDI -Credential $cred  -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"}|Select-Object SystemName,
     @{ Name = "Drive" ; Expression = { ( $_.DeviceID ) } },
     @{ Name = "Size (GB)" ; Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Size / 1gb)}},
     @{ Name = "FreeSpace (GB)" ; Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) } },
  
     $free = $Space.'FreeSpace (GB)'
     $Size = $Space.'Size (GB)'
     $Drive=$Space.Drive
     $Action="     Yes"
                                     
 }
    
 else {$Remoting = "Disabled";}
 }
    
 else {$Isonline = "Offline";}
 $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
                
             'VDI' = $VDI
             'Status'="$Isonline"
             'WinRM'="$Remoting" 
             'CleanUp Performed'=$Action
             'Drive'=$Drive
             'Size (GB)'=$Size
             'FreeSpace (GB)'= $free
             }
 $collection += $object
                 
 }
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "its not working" - does it only run on some? Does it fail completely? Computers catch on fire? Any error messages? If so, what do they say? Please be mindful that only YOU can see you screen :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing `foreach` with `ForEach-Object`. It may help to read a [recent answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438004/where-object-select-object-and-foreach-object-differences-and-usage/65696966#65696966) but the gist is that `foreach` is a looping construct like in other languages, whereas `ForEach-Object` is actually a cmdlet.

Assuming that by "its not working" you mean that it fails to run any iteration and gives you an error message, the solution should be as simple as replacing:

```
# old line
ForEach-Object -parallel ($VDI in $AllVDI){

# new line
$AllVDI | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $VDI = $_
```